# Laravel app with package git workflow

Tags: git, laravel

So I have a new GitHub repository in which my Laravel app lives.

Got this set up and working fine.

I wish to create a package for the app (and plan to make use of this in other projects) and therefore I've created a workbench using artisan.

I've also added another GitHub repository for said package to live in.

I've added `/workbench` to `.gitignore` so that my package development doesn't get committed to the Laravel app repo.

My question is, how do I set up git so that the package in workbench is tracked only by the repo that I've set up purely for the package?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a question with a very big answer. In short though, you don't need submodules. Just navigate to your package's directory in `workbench` and do a `git init`, that'll set a git repository up there for messing with code and pushing. If `workbench` is in your main app's `.gitignore` then the two shouldn't get in each other's way.

However, I found that developing on something within workbench didn't work out too well. First off, when your app is in 'workbench' mode the set up is very slightly different from normal. You'll probably not really notice this, but one large difference is that **any packages that your package relies on in its `composer.json` actually override your main app's packages**. I learned this the confusing and hard way when developing two packages (of which one relied on the other) in the same workbench app. The package that the second package relied upon wasn't actually being executed, as Laravel was seeing the files for it in the `vendor` directory of the second class. Very weird and hard to debug. Anyway, it's unlikely you'll have that exact problem, but it just goes to show that Laravel is in a different 'mode' when you're using the workbench.

Also it makes teamwork a little harder - it's kinda more sensible (though I guess not necessarily easier) to use a development package in composer rather than clone a git repo into workbench. I suppose *this* could be a case where submodules work for you. That said I've been stung by submodules in the past and refuse to go anywhere near them again, but maybe I'm being irrational there!

So my solution is to do this:

1. Make a new workbench package the artisan way just to get set up
2. Ensure composer.json is fine and commit and push it somewhere
3. Remove the workbench folder
4. Add your newly-pushed workbench package to you main app's composer.json, but ensure that you use a develop version (version constraint of dev-master, for example) - this makes composer download the full repository rather than just the absolutely necessary files
5. Now you can develop on the package directly in your `vendor` directory

Points/caveats:

- You must use PSR-based autoloading, as I don't think composer dump-autoload takes into account packages in `vendor` other than when first installed or updated with `composer update`, though I'm not 100% on that. Still, use PSR autoloading and it's all good.
- You can make changes to your files and you don't need to commit and do composer update or anything - it'll just use your files as you'd expect.
- **However**, if you change your composer.json file, you must commit, push and then do `composer update`, as composer will not recognise these changes. This could be changes to dependencies, autoloading rules or anything else that you will need to rely on with your app.

Bonus for teamwork is that everyone can do the same. `composer require vendor/package dev-master` will get them a git repository in their `vendor/vendor/package/` directory.

---

This is all based on my personal experience though. Supposedly there's nothing wrong with the workbench and/or submodules, but I've had issues with both in the past, so I've given up on them. I don't really think there's one *right* way to do this.

Comment: Or you could use submodules.  I mean is this 'very long answer' the right answer? It seems like we are trying to convince ourselves that the hard way is still justified.

Comment: @TimOgilvy yeah this was just my personal experience from developing packages (and specifically packages that may rely on each other, albeit not circularly) back in Laravel 4.2. I have since moved on from PHP/Laravel so it's quite likely that the situation here has changed. And, in fact, I was more addressing the potential issues with using the workbench itself, rather than the specific issue of how to track these workbench files. I only wrote this answer because my 'solution' to the workbench issue was actually also a solution to the question at hand - use a separate repo in development mode.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though after more research, [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) are my answer!